# VIm for each line replace a word based on another word on the same line

Tags: vim

how can I implement the following in VIM

```
substitute/regex_this_word/regex_with_another_word_from_the_same_line
```

e.g

```
select "ali" as name where _placeholder = _placeholder
union
select "sam" as name where _placeholder = _placeholder
```

after applying

```
:%s/_placeholder/anythin_between_quotation/
```

becomes

```
select "ali" as name where ali = ali
union
select "sam" as name where sam = sam
```

e.g2

```
select id, "_placeholder" as vul members_repeater/vul/none
```

after applying

```
:%s/_placehold/\=something_like_regexp(getline('.'),'regexp_pattern_to_select_everthing_after_/vul/")
```

becomes

```
select id, "none" as vul members_repeater/vul/none
```

thanks

Comment: is there only one quotation part in each line?

Comment: well, I just put it as an example, ultimately it's a regexp, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:%s/_placeholder/\=split(getline("."),'"')[1]/g
```

this works in this case:

- **only one** quotation part (replacement) in each line
- the quotation part could be **anywhere** in this line

for example:

```
select "ali" as name where _placeholder = _placeholder
union
select "sam" as name where _placeholder = _placeholder
select _placeholder where _placeholder = _placeholder "foo"
select _placeholder where "bar", _placeholder = _placeholder
```

into

```
select "ali" as name where ali = ali
union
select "sam" as name where sam = sam
select foo where foo = foo "foo"
select bar where "bar", bar = bar
```

**edit**

```
\=split(getline("."),'"')[1]
 |  |      |
 |  |      +--- get current line text
 |  |
 |  +------ split the line with " as separator, pick the middle part ([1])
 |
 |
 +---- using expression replacement
```

**new edit**

so you can re-use the old routine :

```
:%s#_placeholder#\=split(split(getline("."),"vul/")[1]," ")[0]#g
```

this needs only one `vul/` in your line, but there could be text after the **keyword** (with space as separator) something like:

```
select id, "_placeholder" as vul members_repeater/vul/none trashtrash
```

into

```
select id, "none" as vul members_repeater/vul/none trashtrash
```

see this example :

[image]

Comment: one more thing, what if it has more than one quotation part in each line? i know i'm being picky, but we're here to learn, right? :)

Comment: @Ali, if more than one that part, you have to define the rule: `which one is the replacement`

Comment: can't i use regular expression to define which one is the replacement?
like instead of using split() to get the content of the replacement using different function which will take 2 parameters : 1-getline('.') 2-regexp to define which one is the replacement
thanks a lot

Comment: @Ali e.g. `"a" blablah _ph=_ph "b" "c" "d"`, can you tell me, you want to replace `_ph` with what?

Comment: @Kent okay here's what i mean
`select id, "_placeholder" as vul members_repeater/vul/none`

to

`select id, "none" as vul members_repeater/vul/none`

now if i could use regexp to define the replacement
i would do a rule to make everything after 'vul/' to replace everything between quotations on the same line

some thing like
`=regexp(getline("."),"pattern")[1]`
that would only return the pattern as a replacement

Comment: @Ali can you update your question, and add some more examples? the new requirement has no big difference from the old, or I misunderstood?

Comment: mmmm, there's the function `\=substitute(getline("."),'\/vul\/\*','','')`
but it's returning everything not just the matched regexp

Comment: @kent it's giving 
`E684: list index out of range: 1
E116: Invalid arguments for function split(split(getline("."),"vul/")[1]," ")[0]
E15: Invalid expression: split(split(getline("."),"vul/")[1]," ")[0]]`

Comment: @Ali don't know how is done there, but here with your example, worked. see newly updated, I added a gif.

Comment: wow!, thanks a lot,
the problem was, someline didn't match the regexp of the split, so it gave errors

Answer (score 1):

For these lines in particular, that would be

```
s/^\(.*\)"\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)_placeholder\ = _placeholder/\1"\2"\3\2 = \2/
```

Explanations: expressions in between matching pairs of `\(` and `\)` are captures in \1, \2, etc.  Hence, one way to proceed here is to capture everything up to `_placeholder`, and there put it back.  A little unreadable, admittedly.

That solution assumes there is only one expression in double quotes on each line.

Comment: mmmm, can you breakdown to different lines and explain each line, it's very hard for me to read it and understand it,
thanks

Comment: it didn't work :( 
'E486: Pattern not found: ^\(.*\)"\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)_placeholder\ = _placeholder'

Comment: You didn’t copy the backslashes.  Anyway, glad Kent’s solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `sed` if know it, it allow you to use extended regex:

example_with_no_link.txt:

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.core import management
from app import subapp
```

vim command :

```
:%! sed -re "/django/ s/from (.*) import (.*)/from \2 import \1/"
```

This command does followings things :
1. `:%!`: Put all line in stdout
2. `sed -re "/django/` : if there's 'django' in line
3. `s/from (.*) import (.*)/from \2 import \1/` : reverse patterns in parenthesis

In sed, you catch your searched words with parenthesis and write them with `\n`.
The output is redirect to vim.

Comment: @Zulu I didn't see the advantage of using sed in your example. the extended regex of sed -r is not the selling point, the vim regex is much more powerful than extended regex.  vim :s supports \1,\2 as well. but if an external cmd could solve the problem easily and fast, it is a way to go.